# Error while creating ccache for Android Rom on OSX

Tags: android, osx-yosemite, android-5.1.1-lollipop, ccache

I am trying to use ccache to build the rom faster.

the link at http://source.android.com/source/building.html gives the following code:

```css
$ export USE_CCACHE=1
$ export CCACHE_DIR=/<path_of_your_choice>/.ccache
$ prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 50G
```

However i get the following error on line 3

```css
$ prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 50G
-bash: prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache: cannot execute binary file
```

Even if i go into the directory and try to execute it by "./ccache -M 50G" it gives the same 'cannot execute binary file' error.

Can you guys tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem

```
$ export USE_CCACHE=1
```

is supposed to go in your .bash_profile

After that you can give the following command and it will work.

```
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 50G
```